# install ubuntu on a old pc

Tags: system-installation

when I install ubuntu on my old laptop
dell inspiron 2200 tells me this kernel requires the Following
features not present on the cpu pae

unable to boot please identify a kernel for your CPU approprieate

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the default version from the ubuntu website, it's probably 64-bit. You need to download the 32-bit version for your old CPU.

Here's the link for the latest 13.10:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

If you prefer the old 12.04 LTS (Long Term Support):

http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts